# How do I prove this function is bounded from below?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, optimization

$A \in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ a positive definite matrix, $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}. $

$f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by : 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\langle Ax, x \rangle + \langle b, x \rangle + c$$

How do I bound this from below?

So far, here is what I have:

$f(0) = c$

$\lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert \geq 0$

By Cauchy Schwartz, $-\lvert \lvert b\rvert \rvert \ \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert \leq \langle b, x \rangle \leq \lvert \lvert b\rvert \rvert \ \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert $

And by positive definiteness of $A, \exists \sigma \in (0, + \infty)$ such that $\frac{1}{2}\langle Ax, x \rangle \geq \sigma' \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert^2$

Also, we know that $f$ is coercive ie $f \to +\infty$ as $\lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert^2 \to +\infty$

Giving us: $f(x) \geq \sigma' \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert^2 - \lvert \lvert b\rvert \rvert \ \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert +c \geq - \lvert \lvert b\rvert \rvert \ \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert +c $

Am I on the right track or is there another approach? Is there something obvious I have missed?

Comment: The last inequality you get: $$f(x)\ge -|b||x|+c$$ is useless: what happens as $|x|\to \infty$? Indeed, what you want to control is precisely the behavior of $f$ for big $|x|$. Start with the one dimensional toy model $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c, $$ where $a>0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$. Can you show that this function is bounded below? If you can, you should have no problem in adapting the proof to the $n$-dimensional case.

Comment: You have mentioned $\sigma'$ and $\sigma$. Is it a typo and are they the same? If not, what is $\sigma'$?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

The function $g(t)=\sigma't^2-\|b\|t+c$ is bounded below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use (multivariable) calculus, observe that the gradient of $f$ is:
$$\nabla f=A x+b$$
Then, the equation $\nabla f=0$ has exactly one solution, since $A$ is positive definite: $x^*=-A^{-1}b$. At this point, the hessian of $f$ is simply $A$, which is positive definite, so $x^*$ is a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Take an arbitrary direction $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|v\|_2=1$. Since $A$ is positive definite, you have for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ $0\leq\langle Atv,tv\rangle = t^2\langle Av,v\rangle = dt^2$ with $d:=\langle Av,v\rangle>0$. Thus you get $f(tv)=\frac{d}{2} t^2 + t\langle b,v\rangle +c$, which is bounded from below. Because you can cover $\mathbb{R}^n=\bigcup_{v\in S_{n-1}}\mathbb{R}v$ and because $d$ is always positive and the coefficient of the lower ordered term is uniformly bounded for all $v$ ($\langle b,\cdot\rangle$ is continuous and $v$ is chosen from a compact set) you get the statement.